# jQuery fadeOut does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery

trying to create a fancy jQuery banner ad. My content is styled like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <title>Open House : Banner Advertisements</title>
                <style type="text/css">

                article,aside,details,figcaption,figure,footer,header,hgroup,menu,nav,section {display:block;}

                        body { background:#0D3405; }
#container
{
 background:#000;
 width:895px;
 margin:25px auto;
 border:solid 2px #666;
 color:#eee;
 padding:15px;
 min-height:600px;
}
.leaderboard
{
  width: 895px;
  min-height:150px;
  max-height:150px;
  background: #FFFFFF; //url('_images/01Slide_600x300.jpg') no-repeat;
  overflow:hidden;
  position:relative;
  top:20px;
}
.skyscraper
{
 width: 150px;
 min-height:600px;
 background:#FFFFFF;
 position:fixed;
 margin-left:5px;
 overflow:hidden;
}

#tiger
{
margin-left:-160px;

}

#banner1 img
{
 position:relative;
 height:100px;
 margin-top:150px;
 margin-right:180px;
}

          </style>

<script type="text/javascript" src="_scripts/modernizr.min.js"></script>
    </head>
     <body>
<div id  = "banner2" class = "skyscraper">
 <img id = "tiger" src = "_images/tiger_2.png" alt = "_images/saveTiger.jpg">
</div>

<div id = "container">
   <div id = "banner1" class = "leaderboard">
    <h1>free smartphones</h1>
    <img id = "android1" src = "_images/android.png">
    <img id = "android2" src = "_images/blackberry.png">
    <img id = "android" src = "_images/android2.png">
   </div> </br>
  </div>

 </body>

<script type = "text/javascript" src = "_scripts/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type = "text/javascript" charset = "utf-8">
$(document).ready(function() {
saveTheTiger();
 })

 function saveTheTiger()
 {
  $('#tiger').fadeOut(1000);
 //animate( {'margin-left':'100px'},1000);
 }

function banner1adsequence()
{ 
  smartphones();
}
</script>
</html>
```

The thing is, the fadeOut does not work. if you notice the animate function that has been commented out, that does work, which I just put out there to test drive and check if the  id is being called and that does work.

Can anyone pinpoint what's up here?

Thanks

Comment: Works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/6Q49q/

Comment: Are you sure it's not because the CSS rule places the image outside the screen? What does "does not work" mean in this case, anyway? Image not shown at all or not fading out? Errors?

Comment: Does `fadeIn` by any chance work? Which browser/version are you trying to run this in?

Comment: any error? put an alert inside the savethetiger() ..just check the fucntion is called

Comment: It's working on google chrome. Which browser are you trying on ?

Comment: i am trying chrome, and the image is shown displays itself but it does not fade out.

Comment: Is your #tiger inside the viewport because you've used margin-left:-160px; for tiger and animate should work because it's set to margin-left':'100px ?

Comment: Errors in the JavaScript console? Is Rocket's demo not working for you either?

Comment: Rocket's demo does work on the jsfiddle site....the tiger is in the viewport, should not fadeOut work as well ?

Comment: Rocket's demo is the exact same code you have posted here. The problem is somewhere else.

Comment: Why don't you check the console ?

Comment: If your #tiger image is not grater than 160px in width then it's invisible because of margin-left:-160px.

Comment: just posted my entire .html file wit the jquery and css, does this help explain my anamoly better?

Comment: Why are your `script` tags outside/below the `</body>` tag?  Put them inside/above the `</body>` tag.

Comment: that does not make sense, the script tags are below the body tag so that javascript actions take place once I have loaded the entire document, it's a performance thing, and has nothing to do with the fades

Comment: At the end of the document yes... but they should still be INSIDE the `<body></body>` section.  Anything placed outside of `<body>` or `<head>` is invalid HTML.

Comment: this does not help matters, the problem persists, and regardless, putting it in and out does not effect my other animations

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that your CSS `#tiger` places the `img` `-160px` off the screen. Since the class `.skyscraber` is only `150px` in width the `img` will be `10px` outside the screen.

In your `animate` you correct the margin "error" and that is why it works.

Comment: its not an error, it's deliberate coz that's how the image is being made to position,

Comment: It still doesn't help that you are displaying a box of 150px in width and you are positioning it 160px to the left of the screen.. Try to remove the "margin-left" property in your "animate" method and you will have the same error as you have with the fadeout method

Comment: guys, that margin-left is simply so that I can position the image in a specific way in my viewports' dimensions [skyscraper]. I took out the margin-left and the fadeout does not work.....I test drove this by putting an h1 tag instead of the image, and that fades out fine....

Comment: It might be your library that is bugging.. I just tried with a html file on my machine and used this as my library source with succes:

src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"

Comment: thanks Rudy, the fadeOut works fine for everything else other than the img id that is being called here....